# Identify feature tool

Tags: pyqgis

I need to get a feature where i clicked on:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import QGis, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint, QgsRubberBand,  QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature

polylayer =QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Polys')[0]#shapefile
#save current tool
prevTool = iface.mapCanvas().mapTool()
#create tool
curTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(iface.mapCanvas())

def on_click(ptnClick, clickedButton):
    gpoint = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(ptnClick)
    pntBuff = gpoint.buffer((iface.mapCanvas().mapUnitsPerPixel() * 2), 0)
    rect = pntBuff.boundingBox()
    if clickedButton == Qt.LeftButton:
        print ptnClick
        index = QgsSpatialIndex(polylayer.getFeatures())
        # returns array of IDs of features which intersect the rectangle
        intersect = index.intersects(rect)
        print intersect
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(intersect)
        for feature in polylayer.getFeatures(request):
            print "found:", feature.id()
        for feature in polylayer.getFeatures():
            gpoly = feature.geometry()
            if gpoint.within(gpoly):
                 print "Found within", feature.id()
            if gpoly.within(gpoint):
                 print "Found within", feature.id()
            if gpoly.intersects(rect):
                print "Found intersects rect:", feature.id()
            if gpoly.intersects(gpoint):
                print "Found intersects point:", feature.id()
            if gpoly.contains(ptnClick):
                print "Found contains point:", feature.id()

def tool_changed(tool):#another tool was activated
    iface.mapCanvas().mapToolSet.disconnect(tool_changed)
    curTool.deleteLater()

curTool.canvasClicked.connect(on_click)
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(curTool)
iface.mapCanvas().mapToolSet.connect(tool_changed)
```

But I get no result.
Any idea whats wrong or missing?

Comment: You have plenty of debug prints — how far does the code get? Identify the line where it breaks.

Comment: it runs through without any result

Comment: well, does on_click get called at all?

Comment: yes, it prints the clicked coordinates

Comment: try increasing the number of segments in the buffer

Comment: I figured out the problem is a different coordinate system of the map and the layer. I have to transform the coordinates